# R: updating cell values in dataframe1 based on corresponding cell values in dataframe2

Tags: r

I have two dataframes of equal dimensions (1.2 million rows x 5000 cols). Subsets of these dataframes, df1 and df2, are as follows:

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(0,0,1),B=c(0,1,0),C=c(2,1,0),D=c(0,NA,0),E=c(1,0,1))
rownames(df1) <- c("A1", "A2", "B1")
df1
#   A B C  D E
# A1 0 0 2  0 1
# A2 0 1 1 NA 0
# B1 1 0 0  0 1

df2<-data.frame(A=c(106,NA,61),B=c(127,22,10), C=c(9,NA,126), D=c(1,77,54), E=c(99,87,2))
rownames(df2) <- c("A1", "A2", "B1")
df2
#     A   B   C  D  E
# A1 106 127   9  1 99
# A2  NA  22  NA 77 87
# B1  61  10 126 54  2
```

I would like to update the values in df1 based on corresponding values in df2 as follows:
If the cell value in df2 is NA or if the cell value in df2 is less than or equal to 10, then change the corresponding value in df1 to NA. Otherwise, leave the value in df1 unchanged.

I was able to get a logical dataframe that I thought I could somehow use as a sort of lookup table:

```
df1A <- df1
df1A <- ifelse(df2<=10, df1==NA, df1==df1)
# A    B    C    D    E
# A1 TRUE TRUE   NA   NA TRUE
# A2   NA TRUE   NA   NA TRUE
# B1 TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE   NA
```

In df1A, each TRUE cell corresponds to a value in df1 that should remain unchanged and each NA cell corresponds to a value in df1 that should be changed to (or remain as) NA. However, I'm not sure how to use df1A to update df1. Also not sure if this would be the most efficient approach for the task.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `Map`:

```
#Map works like a 'double' lapply
#in a sense that in each iteration the same
#column (in terms of the index) for each data.frame
#will be passed on to x and y
df1[] <- Map(function(x,y) {
  #y reflects the columns of df2
  #so if y is na or less or equal to 10 then return NA else df1
  ifelse(is.na(y) | y<=10, NA, x)
  },
  df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
> df1
    A  B  C  D  E
A1  0  0 NA NA  1
A2 NA  1 NA  0  0
B1  1 NA  0  0 NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Your output did not have A2,D cell as NA (as it was in original df1), but when I submitted the script on my end, it was perfect!  One follow-up question: Is there any limit on the size of the dataframes that will work with this script?  I have gotten the "long vectors not supported yet:" error when I've tried a few other procedures with these large dataframes.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could be of help :). You have accidentally typed `D=c(0,0,0)` in your question when you defined `df1` that's whey there is no `NA` there. There is no particular limit on the size of the data.frames as long as they can fit your RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach.

```
df1[is.na(df2)|df2<=10] <- NA
df1
#     A  B  C  D  E
# A1  0  0 NA NA  1
# A2 NA  1 NA  0  0
# B1  1 NA  0  0 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach using `set`.  It should be efficient as the overhead in `[.data.table` is avoided.  We convert the first dataset to data.table (`setDT(df1)`) and then loop over the columns in a `for` loop.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in seq_along(df1)){
  set(df1, i= which(is.na(df2[[j]])|df2[[j]]<=10), j=j, value=NA)
 }
df1
#    A  B  C  D  E
#1:  0  0 NA NA  1
#2: NA  1 NA  0  0
#3:  1 NA  0  0 NA
```

Comment: And as usual `data.table` should be the best of all if efficiency is important.

Comment: @LyzandeR I thought to post as an answer as the OP mentioned about large datasets in the comments.  Hopefully, it would be useful.  +1 to you as well.

Comment: Thanks @akrun .I feel that since the OP mentions efficiency they should eventually try your code or Ven Yao 's and change the accepted answer. In terms of efficiency it should be akrun > Ven Yao > Lyzander.

Comment: @LyzandeR When dealing with large datasets, the `matrix` approach would cost memory (if I am not wrong), so I would go with `Map`  as 2nd.

Comment: If I wanted to use this solution but wanted the original dataframe structure retained for the udpated df1, will this require I convert it back to a dataframe after execution?

Comment: @KDA You can just do `setDF(df1)` after the replacement if you need it to be `data.frame`

Comment: You are correct @akrun thanks, hadn't thought about this.